# Get newly created document ID in firebase functions error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to get the newly created firestore document id and use it in the same cloud function, but am getting some error!

Here is my cloud function:

```
exports.createNewGroup = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.HttpsError(
            'unauthenticated',
            'only autehnticated users can make requests!'
        );
    }

    // Save a new group document and get the documents ID
    const { id } = admin.firestore().collection('groups').set(data.group);

    // Adding the group id to the groupmember object 
    data.groupMember.groupId = id;

    // Save a new groupmember document with the newly created groupid added
    admin.firestore().collection('groupMembers').set(data.groupMember);

    return 'All is created perfectly';
});
```

When calling the function, I get this error in my functions log:

```
createNewGroup
Unhandled error TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).set is not a function
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, and how to accomplish this?!?! Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set()` methods exists on a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) but you are calling it on a [`CollectionReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html). If you are trying to add a document with random ID then use `add()` method instead. Also both `add()` and `set()` return a promise so make sure you handle them:

```
exports.createNewGroup = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Async function                             ^^^^^
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.HttpsError(
      'unauthenticated',
      'only autehnticated users can make requests!'
    );
  }

  const { id } = await admin.firestore().collection('groups').add(data.group);
  // await it    ^^^^^

  // Adding the group id to the groupmember object 
  data.groupMember.groupId = id;

  await admin.firestore().collection('groupMembers').add(data.groupMember);

  return 'All is created perfectly';
});
```

Do note that `.doc().set()` can also be used instead of `.add()`. Both methods are equivalent.